# "Option not found 'r'" while installing composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to install composer to my cPanel but I can not getting error.

I have used this command to install it.

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

and

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -c php.ini
```

But both command is not working for me.

Getting this error

> Error in argument 1, char 2: Option not found r

Comment: What does `php -v` yield?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're disallowed using -r option which evaluates php code. Try to use wget instead.

```
wget https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
```

Make it executable.

```
chmod +x ./composer.phar
```

Move to bin for global usage

```
mv ./composer.phar /usr/bin/composer
```

Of course I don't know if this is possible in your cpanel installation.

References: [1](https://www.webhostface.com/kb/knowledgebase/how-to-install-composer-on-linux/)

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/getcomposer.org/master/web/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin --filename=composer
```

got it from https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-set-up-php-composer/

or

```
wget 'https://getcomposer.org/installer -O composer-installer.php

php ./composer-installer.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

got from: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-composer-on-cpanel/